# KDE (Kubuntu 16.04) taskbar disappears then reappears every few minutes

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

I recently updated my Kubuntu through the software centre and a whole host of items were updated. I had an issue where the screen would go blank/black after logging in. The CTRL+ALT+F1/7 did nothing

Then it rebooted fine after several restarts and I ran a few commands to update again through the cli.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall sddm
sudo apt-get install --reinstall plasma-desktop
```

All went well and I restarted the machine. All works fine now except that my taskbar disappears completely and reappears a few seconds later. It does this every few minutes.

I checked panel settings and auto hide is off. Does anyone know what could possibly be doing this ?
Please note I am quite new to the whole Linux thing, previously coming from OSX.

Versioning info is as follows:

```
$ plasmashell --version
plasma-shell 5.10.95

$ kf5-config --version
Qt: 5.9.1
KDE Frameworks: 5.39.0
kf5-config: 1.0
```

[image]

Comment: Hi John, same issue for me. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @serfer2 - Hi. Nope I didn't find a solution. We have recently upgraded to the latest LTS of Ubuntu though at work so this made it a moot point :/